# Excel 2003 VBA - Locate Date & Move Relevant data

Tags: vba, excel

I need to automate a process that's not a one-off event, ~500 facilities, each with 100+ assets which are all scheduled for different dates throughout the year for completion. I have a Workbook set up with my main/source sheet as well as 12 month sheets (Jan, Feb, March, ... Dec). What I need is some sort of code that would allow me to search for a particular date and send it as well as other same-row corresponding data to the appropriate sheet.

For example I have an asset that is due for maintenance in June, 6/17/11. I need for Excel to search for it using the month only, and moving that asset as well as it's name, description, cost, etc to the June tab. Ive managed to get it to locate assets searching for "6/" however it cannot find assets with a date of 6/17/11. It copies all needed data and attempts to move it to the proper sheet, when it makes this attempt a Microsoft Visual Basic error code 400 pops up. Any ideas? All help appreciated.

Comment: Not enough characters to post code apparently. Even after clipping down the comments & excess spaces. I can e-mail a portion or all to you, I have a workbook set up for testing purposes if that'd help.

Comment: Just the bit that finds the date and copies the row would be sufficient, or you could upload your sample file to a file sharing site.

Answer (score 0):

see if this helps ...

```
Private Sub FindCells()
    '' step 1, find all the rows containing your date (June 2011 dates hardcoded in this example)
    Dim CollectionOfRowRanges As New Collection
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rgCell As Range
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each rgCell In ws.UsedRange.Cells
            If IsDate(rgCell.Text) Then
                If Month(CDate(rgCell.Value)) = 6 And Year(CDate(rgCell.Value)) = 2011 Then
                    '' for debugging only ... watch and make sure it stops at the right places
                    ws.Activate
                    rgCell.Select
                    Stop
                    '' end of debug code
                    Call CollectionOfRowRanges.Add(rgCell.EntireRow)
                End If
            End If
        Next rgCell
    Next ws
    '' step 2, copy the rows to a new wb
    Set ws = Workbooks.Add.Sheets(1)
    ws.Name = "June 2011 Rows"
    Dim rgRow As Range
    Set rgCell = ws.Cells(1, 1)
    For Each rgRow In CollectionOfRowRanges
        Call rgRow.Copy
        Call rgCell.EntireRow.PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
        Set rgCell = rgCell.Offset(1)
    Next rgRow
End Sub
```